# Relation between Curie temperature and exchange interaction's constant $J_\text{ex}$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I'm running a Monte Carlo simulation on a generic magnetic nanotube. In my results, I found out that the relation between the Curie temperature (that is, the temperature by which a ferromagnetic material stops behaving magnetically and starts behaving in a paramagnetic manner) and $J_\text{ex}$ (the exchange interaction's constant) is linear. A friend of mine (about to graduate as a master in physics) told me that the dependence between those two variables is logarithmic.

My question is: **Where can I find reference (i.e., books or articles) on the subject (the relation between $T_\text{C}$ and $J_\text{ex}$)?** I've tried Landau's and I found nothing; perhaps I'm not looking deep enough.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the exact system is from the description. However, if you are considering the Hamiltonian of the form $\mathcal{H} \sim J_{ex}\sum \sigma_i \sigma_j$ or something similar, then the corresponding partition function will be $Z \sim \sum e^{-\frac{J_{ex}}{k_B T}\sum \sigma_i \sigma_j}$. It is pretty clear that the physics only depends on the scaled temperature $k_B T/J_{ex}$. If there is a Curie temperature, it should scales linear with $J_{ex}$.